# Another question regarding the specific size of stepped ferrules

Tags: frames, shifting, cable, cable-housing

I have a frame with in total 5 brazed-on cable stop with 5 mm inner diameter, on at the [chain stay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mdRV.jpg)  and 4 at the [bottom bracket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqdfa.png), and I'm using 4.5 mm outer diameter shifing cable housing. The standard end caps for said housing however come with 5.6 mm outer diameter and won't fit my cable stop.
I can't for the love of god find a suited stepped ferrule that takes 4.5 mm housing and steps back to 5 mm outer diameter.

Has anyone a clue? Do I have to make one (or 5) myself?

Comment: it seems that [these POP caps](https://jagwire.com/products/small-parts/pop-compressionless-end-caps) kind of serve said purpose, but, being fairly long, not really for the tight radius around the BB... maybe I'll instead try to coat the cutting ends with a layer of fabric tape to reach the 5mm diameter for a snug fit and other than that leave them open.

Comment: it's a good excuse to buy yourself a lathe and make some  :)

Answer (score 1):

This type of housing stop was intended to take a bare 5mm spiral housing.

If you're using indexed shifting, then Jagwire POP ferrules along with either the 5mm compressionless brake housing they're made for or 5mm shift housing (which can be kind of hard to find now but is out there) is probably the simplest. You're right that it may not play the nicest with the bend needed, but looking at the picture I think it will probably be okay. Using Jagwire KEB-SL compressionless brake housing as shift housing works fine.

If you were using friction shifting, spiral housing is the simple answer.

I wouldn't be surprised to learn something else has been made over the years that does what you need here (like from Dia Compe for example), but I don't know of any other ways of doing it with in-production parts. Note a lot of replacement housing caps that fit vintage brake levers have been made that may look kind of like what you need here, but they won't work right with any kind of compressionless housing.

Don't use shift (compressionless) housing without a proper ferrule of some kind. The wires will pull through and it won't work.